# There is way to set different underline color for each mat-tab?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2, mat-tab

I have material angular mat-tab component, i would like to set a different underline color for each mat-tab, i tried to use backgroundColor and selectedTabChange properties but i can't manage that

```
<mat-tab-group backgroundColor="green" mat-align-tabs="center" dynamicHeight headerPosition="below" (selectedTabChange)="onTabChanged($event)">
            <mat-tab label='IPV Model'>Content</mat-tab>
            <mat-tab label='IPV Market Data'>Content</mat-tab>
            <mat-tab label='Collateral'>Content</mat-tab>
            <mat-tab label='Fair Value Level'>Content</mat-tab>
 </mat-tab-group>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. In `@angular/material` version `"^15.1.3"`, you'll see CSS custom properties: `--mdc-tab-indicator-active-indicator-color` allowed to be used.
2. Before proceeding the code, please make sure to specify `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` in your `@Component` decorator.
3. Therefore, the code:

```
.mdc-tab-indicator__content--underline {
  --mdc-tab-indicator-active-indicator-color: orange;
}
```

Comment: that doesnt work at all

Comment: Otherwise, you'll need to set like this:
`
.mat-mdc-tab .mdc-tab-indicator__content--underline {
  border-color: #0CD8B3 !important;
}
`

Answer (score 0):

You can do so with adding class like this:

```
<mat-tab-group backgroundColor="green" mat-align-tabs="center" dynamicHeight headerPosition="below" (selectedTabChange)="onTabChanged($event)">
            <mat-tab label='IPV Model' class="blue">Content</mat-tab>
            <mat-tab label='IPV Market Data' class="orange">Content</mat-tab>
            <mat-tab label='Collateral' class="green">Content</mat-tab>
            <mat-tab label='Fair Value Level' class="yellow">Content</mat-tab>
 </mat-tab-group>
```

and then in your css:

```
.mat-tab-label.blue {
  border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
}
```

You can repeat this with your other tabs.